# Homeomorphism between two connected sets in real line with usual topology.

Tags: general-topology

Let $(R,U)$ be the real line with the usual topology; let $(a,b)$ be any open interval in $\mathbb{R}$. Also let $(-\infty,b)$ and $(a, \infty)$ be two closed connected sets containing $(a,b)$. My doubt is whether  $(-\infty, b)$ and $(a, \infty)$ are homeomorphic in $( R, U)$.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of thinking of one homeorphism, try thinking of two. We can use a linear function to map $(a,b)$ to another open interval, say $(-\frac{\pi}{2} , \arctan (b) )$. Then use a second homeomorphism to map this open interval to the desired $(-\infty,b)$. Can you guess what the desired function is?

You can use the same trick to map $(a,b)$ to $(a,\infty)$